# Using Developer Sandboxes for team development of managed ISV apps?

Tags: managed-package, app-development, isv

Reading [this blog post](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2013/03/salesforcecomforcecom-team-development) about team development on Force.com I learned that one can/should use Developer Sandboxes instead of regular dev orgs for team development.

- Can anyone share opinions and experiences on this?
- Why don't I see the Sandbox menu in my packaging org's menu?

Comment: You're hitting on one of the challenges of team dev on Force.com around packaged apps. Our team used an all unmanaged dev environment with a "staging" Dev Sandbox being the primary master org in our version control system, and corresponded to our stable master branch there. There are advantages of keep dev out of the managed package org that I'm happy to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

If your packaging org is a developer edition (which I would expect it to be), then you don't have sandboxes with those - you only get sandboxes with Enterprise and Unlimited (you also got one with the old free edition, but that isn't available any more).

I think that in the blog post you are referring to, the "unpackaged application development" is actually talking about developing applications for a specific customer/instance.  In this situation it makes a lot more sense than using a developer edition, as the sandbox is created with a copy of your production configuration and thus reflects the environment that you will eventually go live into.  This is how a customer rather than an ISV partner of Salesforce would carry out development, and how we at BrightGen carry out development or customisation on behalf of our implementation customers.

Comment: Good to have you back Bob :^]